# Does anyone have a categorized Geographic coordinate system List?

Tags: coordinate-system, development

We are making a custom desktop application which will project a selected GDB or shapefile to a selected coordinate system. This will be a custom app since most of the users will not have access to GIS or are not even GIS people. The projection will run on a server, which will have the tools.

Problem is, we need the user to specify the projection. Although the list of projections are available (https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/projected-coordinate-systems.htm), it is not categorized... Imagine having a dropdown with 5000 items... So we are thinking 3 levels, like in ArcGIS... But I can't find those categories anywhere. I was hoping an excel file with 4 columns - The WKID, WK Text, Parent, System. This could work well I believe. Unless there is a library somewhere available?

Comment: You can download the official EPSG dataset from https://epsg.org/home.html. Or you can use the SQLite database where Proj since version 6 stores the parameters. If you have GDAL and proj installed you should find the proj.db file somewhere. You can then categorize the coordinate systems as you wish.

Comment: Will your end users really need 5000 reprojection systems? It may be a better approach to simply limit the list to the projections that the users will actually use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the folder structure that ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap uses, it's available online at:

[Geographic coordinate system metadata info](https://github.com/Esri/projection-engine-db-doc/blob/master/objedit/geogcs_inf.txt)

You'll have to mine the text file or use it directly.

The projected and vertical information are in the same folder.

Disclosure: I work for Esri on this part of the software.